# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Allowed memory size of 167772160 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11841137 bytes)

Tags: php

`Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException`

```
Allowed memory size of 167772160 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11841137 bytes)
```

I tried to change `memory_limit` to `1024M`
and `post_Max_size` to `50M`

but still getting that error when trying to generate sitemap

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing the config?

Comment: Did you make sure to change the *correct* config file reported by `phpinfo()`?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YZpB1DC.png looks good?

Comment: "*memory_limit 256M*". There's a configuration file reported by phpinfo. You have to change *that* INI file.

Comment: I had similar problem. I increase limits and error stil occure.You should look for infinite loop in your code. Propably  one of your methods run itself. Checkout your sitemap generator class.